# for-each loop, attempting to use equalsIgnoreCase() method

Tags: java, for-loop, bluej

First question of mine:

Currently I have an assignment in BlueJ where I need to apply for. each loops.
My code is as follows:

**my constructor:**

```
if(isValidPopulation(populationInMillions) && isValidStateProvinceName(provinceStateName) && isValidCapitalCity(provinceStateCapital)) {
         this.populationInMillions   = populationInMillions;
         this.provinceStateName      = provinceStateName;
         this.provinceStateCapital   = provinceStateCapital;
}
```

**one of the methods that helps with my constructor:**

```
private boolean isValidStateProvinceName(String validName)
{
    for(String temp : validStateProvince)
    {
        if(validStateProvince.contains(temp.equalsIgnoresCase(validName))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I wish to make is so that validName can use any cases in the loop statement. Obviously I am executing this incorrectly. I will provide more code if anyone could be so kind to help.

Comment: Your loop isn't looping because you return out of the method on the first iteration. You should make a boolean variable and set its value to true or false then return that variable after your loop.

Comment: @Takendarkk A boolean variable? For what? Either return `true` if "you" found a match or return `false` outside the loop. A boolean variable just "motivates" most new programmers to keep looping. Btw: setting the variables value to `false` _inside_ the loop, would "ruin" it.

Comment: Remove `validStateProvince.contains`! You won't find a `Boolean` in a `Collection` of `String`s.

Comment: What is the type of `validStateProvince`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
private boolean isValidStateProvinceName(String validName)
{
    for(String temp : validStateProvince)
    {
        if(temp.equalsIgnoresCase(validName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, since you are iterating throug `validStateProvince`, you want to compare it to the `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that after checking the first string in the array/list you either return true or false, so if the first string in the list is not the same as the string that is passed it will ignore everything and return false.

You should only return true if it matches, if it does not, then just do nothing. after the loop return false.

so if it is valid it will return true and escape the method, if it checks all the possibilities and nothing matches then return false.

```
private boolean isValidStateProvinceName(String validName)
{
    for(String temp : validStateProvince)
    {
        if(validStateProvince.contains(temp.equalsIgnoresCase(validName))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

also you do not need to do .contains since you are already checking if it matches, so just do the following

```
if(temp.equalsIgnoresCase(validName)) {
    return true;
}
```

if you want to check if a string contains the province then do the following

```
if(temp.toLowerCase().contains(validName.toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
}
```

Hope this was helpful :D